# Concise travel directions for public transportation

Tags: phrase-choice, writing, lists

I'm writing down travel instructions using public transportation. It's a list where each line should essentially contain three pieces of information: what line to use, what direction of the line (i.e. the name of the final destination of the line) and the name of the stop where to exit the vehicle. I've got some concerns about the latter two station names getting mixed up. I'd like my formulations to be short, yet clear, and ideally something a native speaker might be using as well.

Some alternatives that come to my mind:

1. Bus 123, direction Foo, exit at Bar
2. Take bus 123 to Foo till Bar.
3. Take bus 123 towards Foo to Bar.
4. Take bus 123 direction Foo to Bar.
5. Take bus 123 heading for Foo, leave at Bar.
6. Take bus 123 to Bar, direction Foo.

In particular, I'm unsure whether the word “to” would indicate the end of the line or the stop where to exit, or perhaps both depending on context.

Comment: If this is for a specific system, there might be preferred local terminology. On the New York City Subway, it's the borough: *Take the Brooklyn-bound R train to Canal Street*. On the T, it's the direction: *Take the outbound Blue Line to Wood Island*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **to**, more context is necessary since both "Foo" and "Bar" are in the "to" direction.

To break down your instructions

Which bus to take

> Take bus 123

Which direction to go

> *going towards* Foo
>   *in the direction of* Foo
>   *heading for* Foo
>   *for* Foo
>   *to* Foo

Which stop to get off the bus

> *get off* at Bar
>   *until* Bar
>   *until you get to* Bar

It is also useful to say either how many stops or the expected travel time until the destination.

You could also phrase it as

> Take the Foo bus, number 123, until you get to Bar